# Django : db_index and makemigrations

Tags: django

I want to add to existing fields some db_index in my models. I just added `db_index=True`to the model.

I was thinking I would need to run `python manage.py migrate`to apply them on the database. My issue is that no change is detected thus no migration is created. Is it a normal behavior ?

Or is there a specific behavior I'm not aware of?

Thank you.

Comment: which django version?

Comment: Django 1.7 right now, planning to make a migration to Django 1.9 soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you know enough of SQL, you can still create the migration by hand using [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#runsql).

For example: (with PostgreSQL syntax)

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_app', '0001_initial'), # or last mig
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("CREATE INDEX my_table_my_column_ind ON my_table (my_colum)"),
    ]
```

Related: [Creating Partial Indexes with Django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410488/creating-partial-indexes-with-django-1-7)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [index_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#index-together)

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        index_together = ["field_that_needs_index"]
```

then makemigration should work

Comment: Is there really no way to only add db_index? I have 2 / 3 indexes to create on my models ?

Comment: set the db_index in the fields also, but you need migration for it, so add these fields in index_together also.

Comment: Ok. how can I check then that my indexes are created ? Creating thos index_together will not cause issues with writes / or database size ?

Comment: @AlexGrs nope, no issues. `SHOW INDEX FROM [tablename]` will show you the indexes from your tables