# Constrain Django model by field value

Tags: django

Consider the following Django model:

```
class Account(models.Model):

    ACCOUNT_CHOICES = [
        ('m', 'Main',),
        ('s','Secondary'),
        ('o', 'Other')
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES)
```

How can I enforce a database constraint of a maximum of one 'Main' account per user, while still allowing users any number of 'Secondary' or 'Other' accounts? In a sense, I want `unique_together` for `user` and `level`, but only when the value of `level` is `m`.

I know that I can manually check on saving, but I would prefer the database to check automatically and raise an `IntegrityError` when appropriate.

Comment: IMO this has to be handled on Business logic isn't it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with your current model, but if those are the only choices for `level`, consider changing it to a nullable `BooleanField` such as `is_main = models.BooleanField(null=True)` and set it to `None` for secondary accounts. Then a `unique_together` will work because SQL will ignore null values.

Comment: @Selcuk they're not the only options, so I'll update the question. However, your solution will work if I add a third field as you described

Comment: If you're using postgres you can do this with partial unique indexes http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c5441b/1 - here's a sqlfiddle for it - if this is what you're looking for, let me know and I'll create an answer out of it @ZG101

Comment: Yes, in this case you may add a third field and override `.save()` to have it automatically set to `None` if `level` is not `m`. @Trent's solution is better although less portable.

Comment: @Trent Thanks for your suggestion. However, I'd rather stick to using the Django ORM and apply across other databases too

Comment: @Selcuk Can you please make it an answer?

Comment: @Trent IMHO you should still post that as an answer to help future visitors.

Comment: @Selcuk - are you able to add it as an appendix to your answer? Yours is accepted, it will likely see more traffic - my answer is neither Django based nor answers the request directly

Comment: @Trent Sure thing.

Comment: @Trent Actually it looks like it is finally possible to create partial indexes in Django ORM starting from Django 2.2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410488/creating-partial-indexes-with-django-1-7) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with your current model, but if those are the only two choices for the `level` field, consider changing it to a nullable `BooleanField`, for example

```
is_main = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

and set it to `None` for secondary accounts. Then a `unique_together` will work because every null value is unique as far as SQL is concerned (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308014/2011147)).

Since there are more choices for the `level` field as you later clarified, you may add a third field and possibly override the `.save()` method to have it automatically set to `None` if `level` is not `"m"` for extra convenience.

**Edit:** If you are not concerned about portability, [@Trent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389057/trent) has suggested that PostgreSQL supports partial unique indexes, for example:

```
create unique index u_i on accounts(user_id, level_id) WHERE level_id = 'm';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c5441b/1).

**Edit 2:** Actually it looks like it is finally possible to create partial indexes in Django ORM starting from Django 2.2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410488/creating-partial-indexes-with-django-1-7) for details.

Comment: Great find on partial indexes in Django!